# Disable 'Insert Javascript' link for General Link Field in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

Is it possible to disable "insert JavaScript"(or any other type) link which comes by default from "General Link" or "General Link with search" in Content editor as well as page editor?

We are on sietcore 8.1 update 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to sitecore `core` database and remove the item:

```
/sitecore/system/Field types/Link Types/General Link/Menu/Javascript
```

[image]

Comment: can we just disable?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You may want to try denying read access right for given role/user but I guess it will disappear instead of showing disabled  option.